# SSAS cube - calculations

Tags: ssas, mdx

I inherited a cube and I don't quite get what it's doing. It uses a dimension called "date tool" which really have members that have nothing to do with the facts table. It's members have calculation scripted. It plays with the time dimension, so you can get variances across time.

So one of the member calculate prior month variance (script below in Visual Studio)
For example - if I select March in the "date field", then [Prior Month Variance] from the "Date Tool" will give me the numbers for (March - February)

```
([DateTool].[Aggregation].[Prior Month Variance]) = 
[DateTool].[Aggregation].[Previous Month] - [DateTool].[Aggregation].DefaultMember;
```

I want to amend this so that, when I select [month] = January, it display January only and not (January - December)
This is because (they decided to upload YTD data instead of MTD)

Comment: I tried below and it didn't work.       ([DateTool].[Aggregation].[Prior Month Variance]) = 
iif(
left([dim_RPT_period].[Yr-Qtr-Month].[RPT Period Month].currentmember.name,3) = "Jan",
[DateTool].[Aggregation].DefaultMember,
[DateTool].[Aggregation].[Previous Month] - [DateTool].[Aggregation].DefaultMember
);

Comment: it is a "utility dimension" - common structure within most cubes